# Not able to run named query for update operation with 2 or more set parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

```
<query name="account.updateUpdate">
        <![CDATA[update com.xyz.Account  set Level = :level,lastUpdationDate = :lastUpdationDate where id = :accountId]]>

</query>
```

Exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [level, accountId, lastUpdationDate] [
>           update com.xyz.Account  set Level = :level,lastUpdationDate = :lastUpdationDate where id = :accountId

```
]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$39.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$39.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
```

I am trying to execute this query but i am getting above exception and and i have tried this by removing commain set parameter of the named query like

```
<query name="account.updateUpdate">
            <![CDATA[update com.xyz.Account  set Level = :level lastUpdationDate = :lastUpdationDate where id = :accountId]]>

    </query>
```

still its not working. Pls give me solution for this.

And i am using this to load the named query from my Dao

```
Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("account.updateStatus");
        query.setString("level ", level );
        query.setTimestamp("lastUpdationDate", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        query.setString("accountId", accountId);
        Integer count = getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(query.getQueryString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is named `lastUpdationDate`, and you are trying to set it with `lastUpdateDate`. Fix that. In your second query you miss a comma.

But anyway - generally you are not supposed to make updates with queries. Simply Get your object, use the setters of the POJO to set the new values, and persist it. If you insist, you can use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true)` to only update the changed fields (otherwise the generated query will include all fields).

Comment: You may want to prune the space from `query.setString("level ", level );` too

Comment: + a naming convention problems, and using wrapper instead of primitive, etc.. ;)

Comment: but we are not using annotations in our application.

Comment: This was because bulkUpdate was not working in this case so i tried with executeUpdate() it started working.

Comment: with the corrected parameter name, I guess? But still, why do you use queries for updating?